# Regular expression to get the string before anything which isn't a letter

Tags: javascript, regex

See example: `'foo.bar'`, where expected is: `'foo'`.

From other questions, if the character is known, the solution is:

```js
console.log('foo.bar'.replace(/\..*/, ''))
```

If the special character (anything which isn't a letter) is unknown, seemed obvious to replace `\.` with `[^A-Z]`, but it doesn't seem to work:

```js
console.log('foo.bar'.replace(/\/[^A-Z].*/, ''))
```

So the question is, what to put instead of `\.` to match everything which isn't a letter, and not just checking for a dot?

Comment: Why not simply [`^\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/Jq0AAJ/2/) ?

Comment: That is because you added `\/`. Remove it. `/[^A-Z][^]*/i` will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imo, you could use

```
^\w+
```

Which includes the start of the string (`^`)  and *word characters* (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`).
In `JavaScript` this would be

```js
let strings = ['foo.bar', 'test test test', 'fo!bar', '!word!'];
strings.forEach(string => console.log(string.match(/^\w+/)));
```

Answer (score 1):

'foo.bar'.replace(/\W+.*/, '')   ->  foo

^\w, short form is :  \W

See: [w3schools wordchar](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp)